# Google Load Balancer simple url redirect

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have a simple request.

I need to these routes
`/v1/devices/*`
and redirect them to
`/v1/*`

I have set this up
[image]
But it's looking like it's not hitting these routes at all.

We have setup a new API endpoint for the devices to connect to, we can only change the hostname on the devices, so we need to redirect those routes to the new routes.  I would prefer not to have to do that in code if I don't have to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which url are you trying exactly to say that it doesn't work? Can you try to remove the * in the rewrite field?

Comment: i want any routes that come into /v1/devices/ to be routed to /v1. ie. /v1/devices/commands to route to /v1/commands.  we have about 20 routes using the /v1/devices prefix so using a wild card would be the best option for us here.

Comment: Did you try without the start?

Comment: no i haven't, i assume i need to as to route all the sub routes to the correct place, I will try that

Comment: No I talk about the * on the path rewrite: put only `/v1/`

Comment: that is actually what i did end up trying and that worked a treat, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So thanks to @guillaume it was an easy fix.

Updating my Path prefix rewrite from `/v1/*` to `/v1/` this has allowed the routes to come in the correct path as expected.

[image]